# Writing Program to count different letters

Tags: python, string, function, count

Im writing a program that takes in a string and 2 parameters to count the amount of letter e's that fall under the specified parameter. I get the correct count for the 1st and last possibility but not the in between 2 steps. Here is my function:

```
def count_letter_e(string_to_be_counted,ignore_case=True,ignore_accent=True):

    """
    Return the number of times 'e' and its variations appears in a string given the parameters specified.

    Parameters
    ----------
    string_to_be_counted: str
    A string containing e's that need to be counted

    Returns
    -------
    total: int
    Number of times 'e' and the specified variations appear in the given string
    """


    #counting individual letters to be used to calculate totals in if statements
    #Gets all counts of lowercase 'e'
    e_counted=string_to_be_counted.count('e')
    é_counted=string_to_be_counted.count('é')
    ê_counted=string_to_be_counted.count('ê')
    è_counted=string_to_be_counted.count('è')

    #Get all counts of Uppercase 'E'
    E_counted=string_to_be_counted.count('E')
    É_counted=string_to_be_counted.count('É')
    Ê_counted=string_to_be_counted.count('Ê')
    È_counted=string_to_be_counted.count('È')

    #Create a total variable
    total=0

    #check which parameters have been set
    if ignore_case == True and ignore_accent == True:
        total=e_counted + é_counted + ê_counted + è_counted + E_counted + É_counted + Ê_counted + È_counted
        return total
        total=0
    elif ignore_case == True and ignore_accent == False:
        total= e_counted + E_counted
        return total
        total=0
    elif ignore_case == False and ignore_accent == True:
        total= e_counted + é_counted + ê_counted + è_counted
        return total
        total=0
    elif ignore_case == False and ignore_accent == False:
        total=e_counted
        return total
        total=0
```

Here are my sentences that im testing:

```
sentence_1=("ThE weEk will bè frÊe until thÉre is a shÈèp that is freêd from thé pen")
sentence_2=("Thé redEyê fèlt likE a rÊal pain until I got hit in the hÊel by a freE sÈed")
sentence_3=("The frée pÊa made a gêtaway towards thé hèêl of a pÉnquin but only made it to the knEÈ")
sentence_4=("ThErÉ is a knêe that nèÊds to meÈt the queen for tÈsting of léaning pizza")
```

Here are the output vs the desire output for each
sentence 1: 14 v 14 (This is good)
setnence 2: 7 v 8 (This is not good)
sentence 3: 10 v 7 (This is not good)
sentence 4: 5 v 5 (This is good)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The calling of the functions looks like this: count_letter_e(sentence_1,True,True) count_letter_e(sentence_2,True,False) count_letter_e(sentence_3,False,True) count_letter_e(sentence_4,False,False)

Comment: Actually, `count_letter_e(sentence_2,True,False)` from your code gives me 8 (not 7) for the 2nd case.

Comment: And are you sure that the desired result for `count_letter_e(sentence_3,False,True) ` should be 7?

Comment: Woops, I miscounted on that aspect so that one is correct but sentence 3 seems to be wrong still if im not mistaken (or else im counting wrong, which could be the case)

Comment: Woops maybe i just cant count today, but it looks that everything outputs correctly?

Comment: Yep, it looks correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the improvement for your function:

```
def count_letter_e(string_to_be_counted,ignore_case=True,ignore_accent=True):

    chars_to_count = { # chars that will be counted 
                       # based on the "ignore_case+ignore_accent" state

        (True, True):'eéêèEÉÊÈ', 
        (True, False):'eE', 
        (False, True):'eéêè', 
        (False, False):'e'
    }

    condition = (ignore_case, ignore_accent)
    result = 0

    for c in chars_to_count[condition]:
        result += string_to_be_counted.count(c)

    return result
```

Or just the same in a shortcut way:

```
def count_letter_e(string_to_be_counted,ignore_case=True,ignore_accent=True):

    chars_to_count = { 
        (True, True):'eéêèEÉÊÈ', 
        (True, False):'eE', 
        (False, True):'eéêè', 
        (False, False):'e'
    }

    return sum([string_to_be_counted.count(c) for c in chars_to_count[(ignore_case, ignore_accent)]])
```

The value of this approach is not only in a significant code reduction, but also in the fact that all the settings of your function are now in one place - in the dictionary `chars_to_count` - and you can quickly and flexibly change them for other count-tasks.

---

Results:

```
sentence_1 = "ThE weEk will bè frÊe until thÉre is a shÈèp that is freêd from thé pen"
sentence_2 = "Thé redEyê fèlt likE a rÊal pain until I got hit in the hÊel by a freE sÈed"
sentence_3 = "The frée pÊa made a gêtaway towards thé hèêl of a pÉnquin but only made it to the knEÈ"
sentence_4 = "ThErÉ is a knêe that nèÊds to meÈt the queen for tÈsting of léaning pizza"

print(count_letter_e(sentence_1, True, True)) # 14
print(count_letter_e(sentence_2, True, False)) # 8
print(count_letter_e(sentence_3, False, True)) # 10
print(count_letter_e(sentence_4, False, False)) # 5
```

Note that your original code produces the same results.
And it seems that there is no error - based on the logic of the program, the desired results should be the same as in the printout above.

Answer (score 0):

I like @MaximTitarenko's approach, but here's another option. It's not as DRY as it could be, but it makes the counting logic very clear.

```
def count_letter_e(string, ignore_case=True, ignore_accent=True):
    if ignore_case and ignore_accent:
        counts = [
            string.count('e'),
            string.count('é'),
            string.count('ê'),
            string.count('è'),
            string.count('E'),
            string.count('É'),
            string.count('Ê'),
            string.count('È'),
        ]
    elif ignore_case and not ignore_accent:
        counts = [
            string.count('e'),
            string.count('E'),
        ]
    elif not ignore_case and ignore_accent:
        counts = [
            string.count('e'),
            string.count('é'),
            string.count('ê'),
            string.count('è'),
        ]
    elif not ignore_case and not ignore_accent:
        counts = [
            string.count('e'),
        ]

    return sum(counts)

sentence_1 = 'ThE weEk will bè frÊe until thÉre is a shÈèp that is freêd from thé pen'
sentence_2 = 'Thé redEyê fèlt likE a rÊal pain until I got hit in the hÊel by a freE sÈed'
sentence_3 = 'The frée pÊa made a gêtaway towards thé hèêl of a pÉnquin but only made it to the knEÈ'
sentence_4 = 'ThErÉ is a knêe that nèÊds to meÈt the queen for tÈsting of léaning pizza'

print(count_letter_e(sentence_1, True, True))
print(count_letter_e(sentence_2, True, False))
print(count_letter_e(sentence_3, False, True))
print(count_letter_e(sentence_4, False, False))
```